# if Ajax request don't finish, html links can't click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a jquery ajax request in my website page, and every page i need to post this request to server to get the status. But it have a issue: after i open the page in browser, before this request return the data, my page all link can't works, they can't click.But it render normal. so anybody have a solution for that? such as: make the page load this script after page loaded or other.

```
$(function(){      
      var login_status;
      $.ajax({
        async:false,
        url:<%= url(:login_status_header_session, :from => from_uri).to_json %>,
        dataType:"html",
        success:function(data, textStatus){
          login_status = data;
        }
      });
      if(login_status) {
        $(".loginDetails p .login_status").html(login_status);
      } else {
        $(".loginWrapper").remove();
      }
  });
```

this is the login_status_header actin:

> self.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, must-revalidate"
> self.headers["Expires"] = "0" partial "session_header", 
> :format => "html"

Answer (score 3):

First, remove the `async:false,` line. This way the interface will keep responding while the AJAX request is being processed. Second, move your checking of the result into the `success` function - otherwise it runs before the request finishes, and so `login_status` hasn't been set yet (and thus defaults to null, which is treated as false).

```
$(function(){      
      var login_status;
      $.ajax({
        url:<%= url(:login_status_header_session, :from => from_uri).to_json %>,
        dataType:"html",
        success:function(data, textStatus){
          login_status = data;
          if(login_status) {
            $(".loginDetails p .login_status").html(login_status);
          } else {
            $(".loginWrapper").remove();
          }
        }
      });
  });
```

Comment: it seems don't take effect in my side, but still thank you, can you tell me what conditions will cause freezing pages?

Comment: +1 for correctness. Even if it doesn't work async false should not be used

Comment: self.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, must-revalidate"
    self.headers["Expires"] = "0"
    partial "session_header", :format => "html"
end

this is the login_status_headder_session action. 
Is it related that?

Comment: OK...you guys is right..I find the page is cause another problem. $('body').prepend("xx"); this prepend file also cause the freeze problem.

Answer (score 2):

Without more information I can only guess, and my guess is that since you're using `async: false`, the interface is not responding. Is there a reason for doing the request synchronously? If not try removing `async:false` and see if that works.

Comment: No, it need to use this option, if not, page will not load the status code.

Comment: +1 - the reason your page freezes is because of `async: false` like Darko says.

Comment: Can you tell me more details? cause after i remove async:false, my page won't load the status html code.

Comment: You need to put your `if(login_status)` bit inside the `success:` function. Otherwise it's being run before the ajax request returns.

Comment: What Dav says is correct. If you put you if section inside the success then it waits for the async to finish first. then you can get rid of async false

Answer (score 1):

Uhm... without examining your code in too much detail, if this is supposed to occur at soon as the page is loaded, why not just put it on the server side, and generate the proper HTML in the first place? i.e. do it with PHP or whatever you're using and forget the AJAX?